# Javascript: I defined a global variable in function, but can't access it outside the function. why?

Tags: javascript

I want the code the print hi on my browser, but not working.

```
<html>
<p></p>
<script>
    var ptag=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

    var func=function(){
        glob="hi";
    }


   ptag.innerHTML=glob;

 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to call the function first.

Answer (score 6):

The variable doesn't get defined till you call the function. You probably want

```
...
func();
ptag.innerHTML=glob;
...
```